# Why does Entity Framework not respect my Foreign Key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am writing the Entity Framework models [Code-First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) with no existing database. On my objects, I have declared my one-to-many foreign relationships both explicitly and as lazy-loading navigation properties like this:

UserRecord class

```
[Key]
public long ID { get; set; }

public virtual List<WorkItemRecord> WorkItemsAuthored { get; set; } // authored work items
```

WorkItemRecord class:

```
[Key]
public long ID { get; set; }

public long AuthorID { get; set; } // user ID of the author
public virtual UserRecord Author { get; set; } // navigation lazy-loaded property
```

The idea behind maintaining the foreign key both as an ID as well as a navigation property in the WorkItemRecord class is that in cases where I just need the actual underlying author's user ID, I can reference that directly without having to call the property and incur another DB lookup.

The problem is, when EF creates the database schema, it doesn't tie them together. It creates separate columns: `AuthorID`and `UserRecord_ID`

I thought at first maybe this was because my property was `Author` and not `User`. However, even when I explicitly specified it using the property attribute...

```
[ForeignKey("Author")]
public long AuthorID { get; set; }
public virtual UserRecord Author { get; set; }
```

... I still end up with those same two columns in the generated schema.

Also tried putting the decorator on the other property...

```
public long AuthorID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AuthorID")]
public virtual UserRecord Author { get; set; }
```

... and still get the same result.

I'd like to avoid the Fluent API if possible, but I'm open to it if I can't get any other solutions.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help! Fluent API worked fine, but fixing the data annotation with an inverse property decorator proved much easier. Final solution:

UserRecord class:

```
public long ID { get; set; }
public virtual List<WorkItemRecord> WorkItemsAuthored { get; set; }
```

WorkItemRecord class:

```
public long ID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Author")]
public long AuthorUserID { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("WorkItemsAuthored")]
public virtual UserRecord Author { get; set; }
```

Microsoft also has an article talking about this specific issue:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships

Comment: Show us the code of UserRecord ?

Comment: Sounds maybe a bit silly but does the type of `UserRecord.ID` property match the type of `AuthorID` property? Are they both `long`?

Comment: Yes. updated code to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference property should be enough for EF to recognize the one-to-many relationship but do you have a navigation property in the `UserRecord` class as well?

```cs
public class UserRecord
{
    /* other properties */
    public virtual List<WorkItemRecord> WorkItemsAuthored { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe there is a minor detail which causes EF not to recognize the foreign key.

**UPDATE:**
Try `InverseProperty` in the `UserRecord` class as below:

```
[InverseProperty("WorkItemsAuthored")]
public virtual UserRecord Author { get; set; } // navigation lazy-loaded property
```

From the "Programming Entity Framework: Code First" written by Julia Lerman and Rowan Miller:

> ... you may run into a scenario where there are multiple relationships between entities. In these cases, Code First won’t be able to work out which navigation properties match up.

I assume that the `UserRecord` class has more than one `List<WorkItemRecord>`.

Comment: Yes. Updated code in question to include more context.

Comment: Updated my answer so that you can use Data Annotation. That may solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

In you your `DbContext` class add this to your `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>() //Guessing at your class name
    .HasRequired(e => e.Author)
    .WithMany(e => e.Books)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AuthorID);
```

This will enforce the constraint.

Comment: This works, thanks! However, I'm still hoping to find a way to do it with decorator attributes instead of the fluent API since that will be easier for another dev to pick up in the future